# I need help to find a good solution to inject DBContext into Repository Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor-server-side

I have new Blazor project that is sharing a common Repository module with another API project. The Repository constructors services require a `DBContext` instance and an `AutoMapper` instance. I saw that the best practices are saying that I should use `IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>`. The problem is that I can't use it at the inject time into my services, so I came up with this approach that is working for now but I bet there are some downsides that I am not yet aware of them. So any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("PAADB") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'PAADB' not found.");
        services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        services.AddScoped(ConfigurePersistenceService<IUserPersistenceService, UserPersistenceService>);
        services.AddScoped(ConfigurePersistenceService<ICrmFirmsPersistenceService, CrmFirmsPersistenceService>);
        services.AddScoped(ConfigurePersistenceService<ICrmAdvisorsPersistenceService, CrmAdvisorsPersistenceService>);


        .......


        static I ConfigurePersistenceService<I, T>(IServiceProvider provider) where T : class
        {
            var db = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>>();
            var autoMapper = provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
            return (I)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), db.CreateDbContext(), autoMapper);
        }//ConfigurePersistenceService - special way to pass db instance
```

Repository service example

```
public class CrmFirmsPersistenceService : PersistenceService<CrmFirm>, ICrmFirmsPersistenceService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CrmFirmsPersistenceService(MyDBContext context, IMapper mapper) : base(context)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<(IEnumerable<CrmFirmDTO>, int)> GetFirmsWithPagination(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var baseQuery = _context.CrmFirms;

        var lstItems = await baseQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip((pageNumber) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        var total = baseQuery.Count();            
        return (_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CrmFirmDTO>>(lstItems), total);
    }
}
```

}

Exceptions that I get from time to time:

A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

Comment: A DbContext is already a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work. What Repository services do you refer to? Where are their definitions and registrations? Whatever these are, they don't need `ConfigurePersistenceService` or `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos These Repository Services are another abstraction layer over DbContext. So they are not a problem because they work fine for the API. Blazor is the problem because throws exceptions if I use it as for API with  services.AddDbContext instead of services.AddDbContextFactory

Comment: I know what those are supposed to be and they typically aren't. Those single-entity non-repository classes are almost always a *lower level* CRUD implementation, called a Data Access Object. A lot of bad articles are trying to use a DbContext as if it was an ADO.NET Connection instead of a repository. The result, is leaking the data access code all over the business code, *and* breaking transactions

Comment: As for `I saw that the best practices are saying that I should use IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>.` that's a very bad practice unless you understand what they are talking about. There are no "best practices" that need to be followed blindly. In this case, in all web apps *except* Blazor Server,  a new DbContext instance is created for every request. That's the scope of the services too, and that's what gives you transactional behavior for free. In Blazor Server  though, the scope is the entire user session which means you need to create your own scopes for scoped services, not just DbContext

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Yup u are right.... but I still have the problem on how to feed MyDBContext at the injection time into those.... knowing that changing the Repository Services is not an option.

Comment: Do you actually have a Blazor Server app? If not, you don't need a DbContextFactory. No matter what you have, it's impossible to answer *this* question without knowing what the problem is, what the repository classes expect and how they're created

Comment: Yup is a  Blazor Server app

Comment: `I still have the problem on how to feed MyDBContext at the injection time into those.` what are `those`? Post their code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251722/discussion-between-d-a-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: If you want scoped repositories, you need to create scopes explicitly. When you do that, the repositories, DbContext and AutoMapper instances will be created as needed by DI itself. There's never any need for `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: The problem is the incomplete question, not chatting. Add the code and exceptions in the question itself

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos -  Done. Added what u asked.

Comment: I added an answer, explaining the problem with using DbContextFactory in this case, and some of the alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw that the best practices are saying that I should use IDbContextFactory

That's not a "best practice", in fact, in this case, it's a problem.

The actual problem that needs solving is that the DI scope in a Blazor Server application is the entire user session. [There are many options available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) if we need scope semantics, and a specialized factory is only one of them. In fact, DbContextFactory is only meant to generate user-managed DbContext instances. It's not meant to control the lifetime of wrappers or dependent objects.

**DbContextFactory - user managed scope**

A DbContextFactory is meant to be used when we want to explicitly manage the scope of a DbContext only, eg at the function level. It only creates a DbContext, it doesn't dispose it. This is evident in the documentation examples :

```
@inject IDbContextFactory<ContactContext> DbFactory

private async Task DeleteContactAsync()
{
    using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
    ...
}
```

This makes it a bad fit for `CrmFirmsPersistenceService`. At the very least, the service's callers should explicitly dispose the service so it can dispose the DbContext instance in turn.

**Component scope**

One way to solve the problem is to limit the service scope to a component's lifetime. This can be done by inheriting from [OwningComponentBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope).

In this documentation example, `AppDbContext` is scoped to the component's lifetime. It's accessible through the `Service` property :

```
@page "/users"
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits OwningComponentBase<AppDbContext>

<h1>Users (@Service.Users.Count())</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var user in Service.Users)
    {
        <li>@user.UserName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

In the question's case, this would work without requiring a context factory or activator, simply by registering the DbContexts and CrmFirmsPersistenceService et al as scoped services.

The DI configuration could be :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
services.AddScoped<ICrmFirmsPersistenceService, CrmFirmsPersistenceService>();
```

The component itself would need to inherit from `OwningComponentBase<T>`

```
@page "/firms"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<ICrmFirmsPersistenceService>

<h1>Firms (@page.count)</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var firm in page.firms)
    {
        ...
    }
</ul>

@code {

    (IEnumerable<CrmFirmDTO> firms, int count) page = null!;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        page = await Service.GetFirmsWithPagination();
    }
```

**Explicit Scope**

When we want to define a finer scope, we need to create it explicitly with [IServiceProvider.CreateScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and create services using that scope. That's how singleton [Hosted Services can consume scoped services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task).

To do this, we need to add `IServiceProvider` as a dependency to the component:

```
@page "/firms"
@inject IServiceProvider Services
```

Then, when we need to create an `ICrmFirmsPersistenceService` scoped instance, we need to do so through an explicit scope:

```
using var scope=Services.CreateScope();
var firmsService=scope.GetRequiredService<ICrmFirmsPersistenceService>();
...
```

When that scope gets disposed, any scoped serviced created through it will also get disposed, including the `CrmFirmsPersistenceService` and its DbContext

Comment: Thanks, now everything is making more sense.